In statement of 'exact sequence of low degrees' for first quadrant spectral sequence.
I am self studying Spectral sequence and think I am beggner in the domain. I am reading next statement and some question arises :

Proposition F.135 of Gortz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry Vol.2, or Cartan-Eilenberg's  Homological Algebra XV, 5.12 ( Exact sequence of low degrees ).
Let $(E_r, d_r ) _{r\ge 2}$ be a first quadrant spectral sequence converging against $(H^n)_n$.

(1) Then the sequence $$ 0 \to E_2^{1,0} \xrightarrow{e} H^1 \xrightarrow{e}E_2^{0,1
} \xrightarrow{d_2^{0,1}}E_2^{2,0} \xrightarrow{e} H^2$$
is exact. Here all arrows labeled with $e$ are edge morphisms.
(2) More generally, let $n>0$ and suppose that $E_2^{p,q}=0$ for all $0 < q< n$ and for all $p$. Then for all $i<n$ the edge morphisms are isomorphisms
$$ E_2^{i,0} \xrightarrow{\cong} H^{i}$$
and the sequence $$ 0\to E_2^{n,0} \xrightarrow{e}H^n \xrightarrow{e} E_2^{0,n}\xrightarrow{\delta_2^{0,n}}E_2^{n+1,0} \xrightarrow{e}H^{n+1}$$
is exact, where the arrows labeled with $e$ are edge morphisms and where $\delta_2^{0,n}$ is the composition
$$ E_2^{0,n} \xrightarrow{\cong} E_3^{0,n} \xrightarrow{\cong} \cdots \xrightarrow{\cong} E_{n+1}^{0,n} \xrightarrow{d_{n+1}^{0,n}} E_{n+1}^{n+1,0} \xrightarrow{\cong} \cdots \xrightarrow{\cong} E_2^{n+1,0}. $$


I don't understand the below isomorphisms. Can anyone explain what the morphisms exactly means and why they are isomorphic, more friendly ?
Let me deal with the first case  $E_2^{0,n} \xrightarrow{\cong} E_3^{0,n}$. Note that
$$ \ker(d_2^{0,n})/ \mathrm{im} ( d_2^{-2,n+1}) \cong E_3^{0,n} $$, where
$$ E_2^{-2, n+1} \xrightarrow{d_2^{-2,n+1}} E_2^{0,n} \xrightarrow{d_2^{0,n}} E_2^{2, n-1}$$.
Since $(E_r ,d_r)_{r \ge 2} $ is frist quadrant, $E_2^{-2, n+1} =0 $ and by the additional assumption of (2) in the Proposition, $E_2^{2,n-1} =0$. So $E_2^{0,n} \xrightarrow{\cong} E_3^{0,n}$. And how about the next cases ? Can we apply similar approach of this first case ? An issue that makes me stuck is, the condition " $E_2^{p,q}=0$ for all $0 < q< n$ and for all $p$" of (2) in the proposition is only given for the page $r=2$. What should we catch? How can we breakthrough ?

The next cases are all the same, yes. Up until time $n+1$, all kernels will be full and all images will be zero when you compute the next term, so they'll stay the same

@FShrike : Thank you. Perhaps, can you explain for $E_3^{0,n} \cong E_4^{0,n}$ as an example, more in detail?

It continues to be the same. From your notation, I assume a first quadrant sequence of cohomological type, whose second page is concentrated in the $0$th and $n$th row.
Firstly, we can of course agree that all later pages are also concentrated in the $0$th and $n$th rows; a subquotient of zero is always zero.
For $2\le k\le n$, the differential leaving $E_k^{0,n}$ has codomain $E_k^{k,n-k+1}$ and since $0<n-k+1<n$ and $E_k^{\ast,\ast}$ is concentrated in rows $0,n$, this object vanishes. $\ker(d:E_k^{0,n}\to0)=E_k^{0,n}$ of course. What is the differential entering $E_k^{0,n}$? It has domain $E_k^{-k,n+k-1}$. Since $n<n+k-1$, this object is again zero. Therefore $\mathrm{im}(d:0\to E_k^{0,n})=0$; therefore, $E_{k+1}^{0,n}\cong E_k^{0,n}/0=E_k^{0,n}$.
Note nothing is special about $(0,n)$. The same is true of $E_k^{p,n}$ for any $p$; $E_2^{p,n}\cong E_3^{p,n}\cong E_4^{p,n}\cong\cdots\cong E_n^{p,n}\cong E_{n+1}^{p,n}$. Also, $E_2^{p,0}\cong E_3^{p,0}\cong\cdots\cong E_{n+1}^{p,0}$ by a similar argument.
Finally, $E_\infty^{p,n}\cong\ker(d:E_{n+1}^{p,n}\to E_{n+1}^{p+n+1,0})$. And while this is isomorphic with a map $E_2^{p,n}\to E_2^{p+n+1,0}$, this map is not the standard $E_2$ differential so it is perhaps dangerous to write it in that way.

Thank you very much. Two question : Q.1.) Can you explain the second paragraph - applying subquotient argument to conclude that later pages are also concentrated in the $0$th and $n$-th rows- with a simple example? I think this is a key point for subsequent argument for $2 \le k \le n$. Q.2.) Why do you notice the final paragraph? The $E_{\infty}^{p,n}$ -term doesn't appear in my question and why did you warn (?) me  for the term?

@Plantation for q1) it's as simple as, if $E_2^{p,q}=0$ then $E_3^{p,q}=0$ because it is $A/B$ where $A\subseteq E_2^{p,q}=0$... so $A=0$, $A/B=0$. And so on. Subquotients of the zero object are zero, this is simpler than it sounds!

O.K. Thank you :)
